# Can I freely move an SD card imaged with Ubuntu Server for Raspberry Pi between an rPi3 and rPi4?

Tags: server, raspberrypi, sd-card, webserver, arm

Just curious about the implications of such.

I've got a Raspberry Pi 3 that I use to host small web development projects on a LAMP stack (Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi 22.04). I'm thinking of tasking the device with more (file/backup server, media host, torrent server) and I think my Raspberry Pi 4 would probably be more up for the task.

Do I theoretically need to re-image an SD card and boot up the Pi 4 with that card the first time, or could I just swap the SD card into the newer Pi and avoid a lot of setup that has already been done and continue my configuration?

Comment: Should theoretically work (the pi 3 image on the pi4). Practically I would just try ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably just give it a shot this weekend. I may end up wanting a GUI to use it as a set-top media player anyway, now that I think of it. Worth a shot to know if it works though. Thanks.